# HtmlPage.Window { Eval vs Invoke }

Tags: c#, javascript, eval, invoke, silverlight-5.0

**What**'re differences between  :

```
System . Windows . Browser . HtmlPage . Window . Eval ( ... );

System . Windows . Browser . HtmlPage . Window . Invoke ( ... );
```

What I reached till now is

**Eval :**

- Apply JavaScript code applied withen it. ( Code written in Silverlight )
- Invoke JavaScript global methods without parameters . ( Methods written in JavaScript )

**Invoke :**

- Call JavaScript global methods with/out parameter/s. ( Methods written in JavaScript )

If I'm true, are there other differences ?
I really need a simple but powerful difference example.

MSDN References :

- [Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlwindow.eval%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptobject.invoke%28v=vs.95%29)

Finally, **Which** function doing a real injection ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("function addElement(string){ var p = document.createElement('p'); p.innerHTML = string; document.body.appendChild(p);}")  
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("addElement('Eval function');")  
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("addElement", "Invoke function")
```

he add 2 paragraphs on page.
Differences between `Eval` and `Invoke` function is that **`Invoke` calling a function** with (or without) parameters and **`Eval` execute a code**.